# How to run an executable in aws lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa

I am trying to deploy a python file using Zappa. The python file inturn calls an executable which is in the same directory as the python file. It works fine when I run it locally using ngrok but it fails when deployed with Zappa. I understand that we can use this [workaround](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/) for executables in aws lambda using node js. How can I do it using python?

```
class ChessGame:
    board = chess.Board()
    engine = chess.uci.popen_engine("stockfish-8-64")
```

Comment: Did you try using os.chdir()?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your deployment package by using virtual env.

Refer this AWS documentation for more details. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html